# After response.sendRedirect(redirect) session becomes null

Tags: java, servlets

Here request is an object type which extends `HttpServletRequest`. This is the sequence of code.

```
HttpSession session; 

session = request.getSession(false);

response.sendRedirect(redirect);

session = request.getSession(false);
```

In the first line, able to get the valid session value. But after 2nd statement `sendRedirect` execution. `session` object is becoming `NULL` in the 3rd statement.

Comment: it would have been better, if you paste the actual code here.

Comment: actually there is nothing special we are doing in sendRedirect() that affects request's session, its just an inbuilt method.

Comment: but you are passing an argument in 'redirect', what does it contain?

Comment: Also, how are you initializing request object ie.`psrequest` and `request`

Comment: its a string- simply an URL

Answer (score 0):

For the redirected request to come back and attach to the same session, it needs a session ID, usually carried in a JSESSIONID (or another name) cookie or in the URL as a parameter.

This cookie or URL parameter should be added by the servlet container and you should not have to add it yourself.

If you do not see the cookie in your browser, and you are not attaching the JSESSIONID to the URL, then it is creating a new session with each request, and not attaching to the same session